# CloudFront delivery is slow in particular location

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cloudflare, amazon-cloudfront

In our scenario, I found that our CloudFront delivery particularly in the Japan area is very slow for a few days. which lead our site to become slow in the time of loading the media contents .our s3 origin is in the Northern Virginia region. what might be the possible issues of this? or if something is not configured correctly?

Can anyone help me to figure this out? Is there way to identify the root cause of it? or do we rely on any log data, monitoring system in suggestion ??

Are Cache key and origin requests to Cache policy and origin request policy (recommended)changes will improve the performance?
screenshots attached

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/denc6.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IbHCa.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5pEK.jpg)

Comment: If something that has been working well has slowed and you haven't made changes I would reach out to AWS Support. If you don't have AWS support consider the developer level which is sufficient for non-urgent queries.

Comment: Do I need to change the Cache key and origin requests to the Cache policy and origin request policy (recommended)changes will improve the performance?

Comment: Difficult to say since you haven't told us anything about your configuration.

Comment: Which Configuration are you talking about, can you be specific? attached screenshot of CloudFront delivery with the question?

Comment: Ok I see CloudFront config now. There's obviously latency between Japan and us-east-1, about 160ms, which might not be helping, but if other regions are ok then it's probably not that. You could have a play with caching policy instead of legacy cache settings. Beyond that I think AWS Support is the way to go for this query.